# Quantlib Vanilla Swap Amount not based on Forwards

Tags: derivatives, quantlib, swaps, hedge

I have the following code:

```
        cashflows = pd.DataFrame({
            'Nominal': cf.nominal(),
            'AccrualStartDate': cf.accrualStartDate().ISO(),
            'AccrualEndDate': cf.accrualEndDate().ISO(),
            'AccrualPeriod': cf.accrualPeriod(),
            'Price': cf.price(disco_yts),
            'Rate': cf.rate(),
            'Amount': cf.amount(),
            'Forward': cf.indexFixing(),
            'FloatAccruedAmount': cf.accruedAmount(valuation_date+1)
        } for cf in map(ql.as_floating_rate_coupon, swap.leg(1)))

        fixed_cashflows = pd.DataFrame({
            'FixedAmount': cf.amount(),
            'FixedAccruedAmount': cf.accruedAmount(valuation_date+1)
        } for cf in map(ql.as_fixed_rate_coupon, swap.leg(0)))

swap.NPV()
```

My issue is that amount (from floating leg) is not as expected.

Mathematically I want amount to be

amount = nominal x accrualperiod x forward
,

but instead it seems as though Quantlib is doing something completely different? This is strange because 99% of the time it does create amounts as expected. What am I missing?

|  | TradeId | Nominal | AccrualPeriod | Price | Forward | Amount | ExpectedAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | bob | -2421350000 | 0.084931507 | -20443249.84 | 0.06458 | - 20 478 517.87 | - 13 280 806.23 |
| 1 | bob | -2421350000 | 0.252054795 | -61382112.76 | 0.067465903 | - 62 536 259.86 | - 41 175 309.17 |
| 2 | bob | -2421350000 | 0.243835616 | -63886355.38 | 0.077314926 | - 66 312 009.20 | - 45 647 611.25 |
| 3 | bob | -2421350000 | 0.252054795 | -65823488.94 | 0.079179836 | - 69 685 424.07 | - 48 324 473.39 |
| 4 | bob | -2421350000 | 0.252054795 | -65385660.54 | 0.080726366 | - 70 629 291.20 | - 49 268 340.52 |

Comment: May you share the code you're using to build the swap?  And may you also show the column for Rate in the table?

Comment: Thanks @LuigiBallabio, I just figured out that I have a spread for that specific trade. 

So the amount is determined by the rate, not the forward.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Mr Ballabio, the Amount column is determined by nominal x accrualperiod x rate, not forward, when a spread occurs.